# Bootstrap Progress Bar: add to the css: width value, all in coffeescript / jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I'm trying to make it so that each time the button is pressed, the progress bar adds an *additional* 12.5% out of 100%.  (So eight clicks will make the bar add up to 100%)

Currently It adds the text but does not move the progress bar.

Code so far:

**coffeescript**

```
$(".mybtn").on 'click', (e) ->
    valuer = $("#progBarMsg").parent().attr('value')
    newVal = valuer + 12.5
    e.preventDefault()
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    $("#progBarMsg").parent().css("width", newVal+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', newVal)
    $("#progBarMsg").text("This is a test")
```

Here is the view partial, just showing the progress bar and the button:

**rails partial**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 12.5%;">
    <span id="progBarMsg">Step 1 of 8</span>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="mybtn"><a href="">Click to Fill Progress Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it:

**rails partial**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 12.5%;">
    <span id="progBarMsg">Step 1 of 8</span>
  </div>
</div>


<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="myBtn"><a href="">Hit button to add to Progress</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**coffeescript**

```
$(".myBtn").on 'click', (e) ->
    valuer = $("#progBarMsg").parent().attr('aria-valuenow')
    newVal = Number(valuer) + 12.5
    e.preventDefault()
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    $("#progBarMsg").parent().css("width", newVal+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', newVal)
    $("#progBarMsg").text("This is a test")
```